# SSH Commandline - Ubuntu x64 dedicated server raid-0 array creation LOG [ After reboot : Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table ]

Tags: 12.04, command-line, ssh, raid

> I followed this tutorial but failed as it seems, i tried for a couple times, here i throw the towel:

ht-tp://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2012/07/setting-up-raid0-in-ubuntu-12-04-in-aws-high-io/

> The raid creation command i used was `mdadm --create --verbose
>   --auto=yes --chunk=64 /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`
>
> OBV something went wrong as `fdisk -ls` prints `Disk /dev/md127
>   doesn't contain a valid partition table` after the reboot.
>
> Iam looking for a solution to get this correctly setup.

The full install LOG is:

> login as: root root@"serverIP"'s password: Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1
>   LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-35-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  ht-tps://help.ubuntu.com/ You have mail. Last login:
>     Thu Dec 20 11:11:17 2012 from p4fe4fd1a.dip.t-dialin.net

root@j064:~# `fdisk -ls`

> Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00025802
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1             261     7812500     3906120   82  Linux swap /
>   Solaris /dev/sda2   *     7813120   249554943   120870912   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xe92120fa
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

root@j064:~# `apt-get install mdadm`

> Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree Reading state information... Done The following NEW
>   packages will be installed:   mdadm 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0
>   to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 520 kB of archives. After
>   this operation, 1185 kB of additional disk space will be used. Get:1
>   ht-tp://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main mdadm amd64
>   3.2.5-1ubuntu0.2 [520 kB] Fetched 520 kB in 0s (1030 kB/s) Preconfiguring packages ... Selecting previously unselected package
>   mdadm. (Reading database ... 76517 files and directories currently
>   installed.) Unpacking mdadm (from
>   .../mdadm_3.2.5-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb) ... Processing triggers for
>   ureadahead ... Setting up mdadm (3.2.5-1ubuntu0.2) ... Generating
>   mdadm.conf... done.  Removing any system startup links for
>   /etc/init.d/mdadm-raid ... update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger
>   activated)  * Starting MD monitoring service mdadm --monitor
>   [ OK ] Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ... update-initramfs:
>   Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic W: mdadm:
>   /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

root@j064:~# `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`

Command (m for help): `d`

> No partition is defined yet!

Command (m for help): `n`

Partition type:    `p`

> primary (0 primary, 0
>   extended, 4 free)    e   extended Select (default p): p Partition
>   number (1-4, default 1): Using default value 1 First sector
>   (2048-1953525167, default 2048): Using default value 2048 Last sector,
>   +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-1953525167, default 1953525167): Using default value 1953525167

Command (m for help): `t`

> Selected partition 1 Hex code (type L to list
>   codes): `fd`
>
> Changed system type of partition 1 to fd (Linux raid
>   autodetect)

Command (m for help): `w`

> The partition table has been altered!
>
> Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table. Syncing disks.

root@j064:~# `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`

> Device contains neither a valid DOS
>   partition table, nor Sun, SGI or OSF disklabel Building a new DOS
>   disklabel with disk identifier 0x8d60ef66. Changes will remain in
>   memory only, until you decide to write them. After that, of course,
>   the previous content won't be recoverable.
>
> Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by
>   w(rite)

Command (m for help): `d`

> No partition is defined yet!

Command (m for help): `n`

Partition type:    `p`

> primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)    e   extended Select (default p): `p` >Partition
>   number (1-4, default 1): Using default value 1 First sector
>   (2048-1953525167, default 2048): Using default value 2048 Last sector,
>   +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-1953525167, default 1953525167): Using default value 1953525167

Command (m for help): `t`

> Selected partition 1 Hex code (type L to list codes): `fd`
>
> Changed system type of partition 1 to fd (Linux raid autodetect)

Command (m for help): `w`

> The partition table has been altered!
>
> Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table. Syncing disks.

root@j064:~# `fdisk -ls`

> Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00025802
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1             261     7812500     3906120   82  Linux swap /
>   Solaris /dev/sda2   *     7813120   249554943   120870912   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xe92120fa
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdb1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x8d60ef66
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdc1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   `autodetect

root@j064:~# `sudo mdadm --create --verbose --auto=yes --chunk=64 /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`

> mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata mdadm: array /dev/md0
>   started.

root@j064:~# `sudo apt-get install xfsprogs`

> Reading package
>   lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information...
>   Done The following extra packages will be installed:   libreadline5
>   Suggested packages:   xfsdump attr quota The following NEW packages
>   will be installed:   libreadline5 xfsprogs 0 upgraded, 2 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 1354 kB of
>   archives. After this operation, 3082 kB of additional disk space will
>   be used.

Do you want to continue [Y/n]? `Y`

> Get:1 ht-tp://filepile.fastit.net/ubuntu/ precise/main libreadline5 amd64
>   5.2-11 [128 kB] Get:2 ht-tp://filepile.fastit.net/ubuntu/ precise/main xfsprogs amd64 3.1.7 [1226 kB] Fetched 1354 kB in 0s (1991 kB/s)
>   Selecting previously unselected package libreadline5. (Reading
>   database ... 76568 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Unpacking libreadline5 (from .../libreadline5_5.2-11_amd64.deb) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package xfsprogs. Unpacking xfsprogs
>   (from .../xfsprogs_3.1.7_amd64.deb) ... Setting up libreadline5
>   (5.2-11) ... Setting up xfsprogs (3.1.7) ... Processing triggers for
>   libc-bin ... ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
>   root@j064:~# `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md0` mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
>   Filesystem label= OS type: Linux Block size=4096 (log=2) Fragment
>   size=4096 (log=2) Stride=16 blocks, Stripe width=32 blocks 122101760
>   inodes, 488380768 blocks 24419038 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the
>   super user First data block=0 Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
>   14905 block groups 32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
>   8192 inodes per group Superblock backups stored on blocks:
>           32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
>           4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
>           102400000, 214990848
>
> Allocating group tables: done Writing inode tables: done Creating
>   journal (32768 blocks): done Writing superblocks and filesystem
>   accounting information: done

root@j064:~# `mkdir /mnt/bigraid`

root@j064:~# `mount /dev/md0 /mnt/bigraid/`

root@j064:~# `df -h`

> Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use%
>   Mounted on /dev/sda2       114G  2.7G  106G   3% / udev
>   3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev tmpfs           1.6G  284K  1.6G   1% /run none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock none            3.9G
>   0  3.9G   0% /run/shm /dev/md0        1.8T  196M  1.7T   1%
>   /mnt/bigraid root@j064:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/bigraid/somefile
>   bs=512 ^C10271932+0 records in 10271931+0 records out 5259228672 bytes
>   (5.3 GB) copied, 20.3628 s, 258 MB/s

root@j064:~# `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/bigraid/somefile bs=2048`

```
^C
```

> 1083452+0 records in 1083452+0 records out 2218909696 bytes (2.2 GB)
>   copied, 10.4948 s, 211 MB/s

root@j064:~# `root@j064:~# hdparm -t /dev/md0`

> /dev/md0:  Timing buffered disk reads: 582 MB in  3.00 seconds =
>   193.96 MB/sec

root@j064:~# `fdisk -ls`

> Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00025802
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1             261     7812500     3906120   82  Linux swap /
>   Solaris /dev/sda2   *     7813120   249554943   120870912   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xe92120fa
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdb1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x8d60ef66
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdc1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> Disk /dev/md0: 2000.4 GB, 2000407625728 bytes 2 heads, 4
>   sectors/track, 488380768 cylinders, total 3907046144 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072
>   bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

root@j064:~# `cd /mnt/bigraid`

root@j064:/mnt/bigraid# `reboot`

> login as: root root@"IP"'s password: Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
>   (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-35-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  ht-tps://help.ubuntu.com/ You have mail. Last login:
>     Thu Dec 20 11:14:36 2012 from p4fe4fd1a.dip.t-dialin.net

root@j064:~# `fdisk -ls`

> Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00025802
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1             261     7812500     3906120   82  Linux swap /
>   Solaris /dev/sda2   *     7813120   249554943   120870912   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xe92120fa
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdb1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x8d60ef66
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdc1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> Disk /dev/md127: 2000.4 GB, 2000407625728 bytes 2 heads, 4
>   sectors/track, 488380768 cylinders, total 3907046144 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072
>   bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table

root@j064:~# `partprobe`

root@j064:~# `reboot`

> login as: root root@"IP"'s password: Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
>   (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-35-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  ht-tps://help.ubuntu.com/ You have mail. Last login:
>     Thu Dec 20 11:36:04 2012 from p4fe4fd1a.dip.t-dialin.net

root@j064:~# `fdisk -ls`

> Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00025802
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1             261     7812500     3906120   82  Linux swap /
>   Solaris /dev/sda2   *     7813120   249554943   120870912   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xe92120fa
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdb1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x8d60ef66
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdc1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> Disk /dev/md127: 2000.4 GB, 2000407625728 bytes 2 heads, 4
>   sectors/track, 488380768 cylinders, total 3907046144 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072
>   bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table

root@j064:~#

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems in your log. Since you created your file system directly on the RAID (without creating a partition table) you cannot expect that there is one after reboot...

With this command you clearly make a filesystem on to the RAID directly:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md0
```

It seems that the kernel gave a new name to the RAID after reboot (/dev/md127), try it to mount from the new device...

```
mount /dev/md127 /mnt/bigraid/
```

By the way, why do you install xfsprogs when you are going to create a ext4 filesystem afterwards?

Comment: Create a mdadm.config file to make sure it gets the same name as before (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/mdadm.conf.5.html)

Comment: hi, thx for your attention! iam a new ubuntu user, i intended to make the filesystem ext4 and recognized it afterwards.

Why does the drives show up as md127 instead of md0 fer reboot?

I will follow your instructions and give feedback.

Comment: sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md0
mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Could not stat /dev/md0 --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?

Comment: root@j064:~# fdisk -ls
Disk /dev/md127: 2000.4 GB, 2000407625728 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 488380768 cylinders, total 3907046144 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: @ falstaff im trying to get it, brb

Comment: well, the server appears to be shot- maybe i should have formulated the question differently to "what are the correct steps to install raid-0 on ubuntu server 12.04 ssh commandline with ext4 filesystem when SDA is os and raid should be installed on sdb & sdc?"

Comment: I recreated the whole thing and created a etc/mdadm/mdadm.config file with "ARRAY /dev/md0 devices=/dev/sdb1,/dev/sdc1 level=raid0 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=j064.jade.fastwebserver.de:0 UUID=473ec040:b4a08f65:1d8efd8b:0a1e91cd"  entry. after reboot fdisk -ls still shows /dev/md127

Comment: Hm, do you see something in the logfiles (/var/log/syslog) or in the kernel messages (command `dmesg`)? You are on a good path. It's only, that the kernel gave your RAID a new name. You also can just work with the new name. (e.g. `mount /dev/md127 /mnt/bigraid/` or add an approprate entry to the file /etc/fstab, so your filesystem gets mounted automatically.

Comment: The last time i tried to put an entry in the fstab i shot the srever (see above, just forgot to mention that).

root@j064:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : active raid0 sdc1[1] sdb1[0]
      1953523072 blocks super 1.2 64k chunks

unused devices: <none>

Comment: desg says:
 3.446475] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 2000407625728
[    3.447488]  md127: unknown partition table
[    3.449373] raid6: int64x1   2591 MB/s
[    3.517291] raid6: int64x2   3675 MB/s
[    3.585337] raid6: int64x4   2417 MB/s
[    3.653319] raid6: int64x8   2345 MB/s
[    3.721297] raid6: sse2x1    7647 MB/s
[    3.789252] raid6: sse2x2    8985 MB/s
[    3.857284] raid6: sse2x4    9960 MB/s
[    3.857285] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (9960 MB/s)

now im really confused, il revert it again and try another partition name.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qUn2cTuc -->  again md127, trying fstab again now, hope it doesent breaks all .

Comment: /dev/md0         /mnt/bigraid  ext4    defaults  0 0  <--  is that correct for the fastab?

Comment: well, server down after editing the fstab as above....

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764861  has solved the issue that it gets mounted on reboot as /dev/md127 instead of /dev/mdX

Comment: fdisk -ls --> Disk /dev/md11: 2000.4 GB, 2000407232512 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 488380672 cylinders, total 3907045376 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md11 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: Fstab entry also works ie, server is booting up FSTAB --> "/dev/mdX /mnt/folder    ext4    defaults    0 0" but still fdisk -ls shows  "Disk /dev/md11 doesn't contain a valid partition table"

Comment: Finally, i partitioned /dev/mdX to /dev/mdXp1 and edited the fstab according to it. I was able to format the partition to ext4 and it seems to work and automount after reboot.

Comment: Going to reverse and redo - to write a correct answer here.

Comment: Well yes, you can create a Partition table on a RAID. However, it should not be mandatory! You can create filesystems directly on a RAID. fdisk is an utility to read/create partition tables. Thats why it complains that there is no partition table on the RAID.

Comment: Your fstab entry looks good. However, if the server detects the RAID always as md127 after reboot, you have to alter the entry accordingly: `/dev/md127 /mnt/bigraid ext4 defaults 0 0`. Also you have to append this entry (leave the other entries in place, and add that one at the end of the file.
Check using `df -h` after reboot to see if mount succeeded.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rQggRus3  <-- All redone from scratch, seems to me it works, may somebody confirm so ill take the time to write the full answer here. Thx 4all help! - Concerning the partition if its no disadvantage ill want to keep it this way.